# is threeBSP can't act on the element that use THREE.ExtrudeGeometry created?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I create a car use THREE.ExtrudeGeometry, and following is my code :

```
function setExtMaterial(drawFunc,options,meshMaterial){
    var geom = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(drawFunc(),options);
    var shape = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geom, [meshMaterial]);
    return shape;
}
function drawShap1(){
        var shape = new THREE.Shape();
        shape.moveTo(10,10);
        shape.splineThru([
            new THREE.Vector2(10.2,11.8),
            new THREE.Vector2(12,12)
        ])
        shape.lineTo(18,12);
        shape.splineThru([
            new THREE.Vector2(19.8,11.8),
            new THREE.Vector2(20,10)
        ])
        shape.lineTo(20,4);
        shape.lineTo(10,4);
        shape.lineTo(10,10);
        return shape;
    }
    var options1 = {
        amount:25,
        bevelThickness:1,
        bevelSize:1,
        beveSegments:60,
        steps:60,
        curveSegments:60
    }
    var mesh2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color:new THREE.Color('#FAF808')
    });
    var carBody = setExtMaterial(drawShap1,options1,mesh2);
    carBody.position.set(-10,-3,15);
    carBody.rotation.y = Math.PI/2;
    car.add(carBody);
    console.log(carBody)
```

Now I use `console.log('carBody')` to see what print ,and result is:

> Group {uuid: "896051F5-8F4E-43C8-8EFE-B9FC4A07B7DE", name: "", type:
>   "Group", parent: Object3D, children: Array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHsHd.png)…}

The carBody is Group ?!

And now I use subtract():

```
function subtract(obj1,obj2,mesh,target){
        var o1BSP = new ThreeBSP(obj1);
        var o2BSP = new ThreeBSP(obj2);
        var r = o1BSP.subtract(o2BSP);
        var result = r.toMesh(mesh);
        result.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
        result.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
        target.add(result);
    }
var windowFront = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,5,9),mesh1);
windowFront.position.set(16,6,0);
subtract(carBody,windowFront,mesh2,car);
```

And when I use threeBSP's subtract() chrome point out this information:

[image]

And I look at ThreeBSP.js's code ,it seems that just Geometry and Mesh can use subtract() to create like this door:

[image]

How to use subtract() on the element that we create with THREE.ExtrudeGeometry. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because `THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject()` returns `THREE.Group()`, which contains several objects of the same geometry, but with different materials. Thus, it's better to do all operations with geometry and then create a multimaterial object, based on this geometry.

Comment: thank you very much